# How can I call a selector from an extension?

Tags: swift, uitableview, extension-methods, uirefreshcontrol

I have added a refresh controller to a table view using an extension:

```
extension UITableViewController {
    func addRefreshController() {
        self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        self.refreshControl?.tintColor = UIColor.init(colorFromHexaString: VIOLET_COLOR_HEX_STRING)
        self.refreshControl?.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.init(colorFromHexaString: VIOLET_COLOR_HEX_STRING)])
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl!)
    }
}
```

It's showing this error:

> Value of type 'UITableViewController' has no member 'refresh'

But the selector `func` is in the `TableViewController`.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
      override func viewDidLoad() {
            addRefreshController()
      }
      @objc func refresh () {
      }
}
```

So, how can I call the selector from an extension?

Comment: Are you sure you correctly added the `UITableViewController` extension? 'cause you should be able to see the extension method from a child class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend your own class, `TableViewController` instead of `UITableViewController` if you want to access the selectors of `TableViewController`.

```
extension TableViewController { [...] }
```